# Struts2 / GAE : SEVERE: Template processing error

Tags: java, google-app-engine, struts2

I am following this tutorial to integrate Struts2 with Google App Engine :

http://www.mkyong.com/google-app-engine/google-app-engine-struts-2-example/

My build path looks like this:

[image: Struts2 app engine]

But i have the following stack trace:

> SEVERE: Template processing error: "Expression parameters.templateDir
>   is undefined on line 23, column 15 in template/xhtml/form.ftl."
>
> Expression parameters.templateDir is undefined on line 23, column 15
>
> ### in template/xhtml/form.ftl. The problematic instruction:
>
> ==> ${parameters.templateDir} [on line 23, column 13 in template/xhtml/form.ftl]  in include
>   "/${parameters.templateDir}/xhtml/form-validate.ftl" [on line 23,
>
> ### column 1 in template/xhtml/form.ftl]
>
> Java backtrace for programmers:
>   ---------- freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression parameters.templateDir is undefined on line 23, column 15 in
>   template/xhtml/form.ftl.  at
>   freemarker.core.TemplateObject.assertNonNull(TemplateObject.java:125)
>     at freemarker.core.Expression.getStringValue(Expression.java:118)   at
>   freemarker.core.Expression.getStringValue(Expression.java:93)     at
>   freemarker.core.DollarVariable.accept(DollarVariable.java:76)     at
>   freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)   at
>   freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)     at
>   freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)   at
>   freemarker.core.Environment.renderElementToString(Environment.java:1594)
>     at
>   freemarker.core.StringLiteral.getStringValue(StringLiteral.java:101)
>     at freemarker.core.Include.accept(Include.java:124)     at
>   freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)   at
>   freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)     at
>   freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)   at
>   freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:199)     at
>   freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:237)   at
>   org.apache.struts2.components.template.FreemarkerTemplateEngine.renderTemplate(FreemarkerTemplateEngine.java:157)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.mergeTemplate(UIBean.java:559)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.components.ClosingUIBean.start(ClosingUIBean.java:59)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doStartTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:53)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.User.pages.login_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005fform_005f0(login_jsp.java:101)
>     at org.apache.jsp.User.pages.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:73)
>     at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet.access$101(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:23)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet$2.run(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:61)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet.service(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:58)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:327)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletDispatcherResult.doExecute(ServletDispatcherResult.java:157)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)   at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:374)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:278)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:90)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:192)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:510)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at